# My images will not center

Tags: css, xhtml, image, alignment

So I'm working on a website for my AP Computer Science class using XHTML, and part of the assignment is to create a click-able image that will link to an external website. I've done this before, and the images that I have will link, but they won't align center like I'm telling them to.

Below is the code from the html file.

```
<p class="display">
<a href="http://www.minecraft.net"><img src="Images/mclogo.png" width="200%" alt="Minecraft logo linked to MC's website" /></a></p>
```

And below this is the code that defines the class "display"

```
p.display {text-align:center;}
```

Could you help to identify my problem. I've asked my compsci teacher, and he said he couldn't see anything wrong.

Thanks,

LordRaiden15

Answer (score 3):

Just remove width="200%" from the image.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/vX3vC/

An image width in percentage defines a percentage of it's parent's width, not of the original image. In fact you are trying to make the image twice as big as the parent, which won't work and it stops at 100%, consequently not being able to align center as it already fills the whole space.

Found here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/objects.html#adef-width-IMG

*Note that lengths expressed as percentages are based on the horizontal or vertical space currently available, not on the natural size of the image, object, or applet.*

Either specify the width in pixels, or make the image the correct size and remove the width specification altogether.

Comment: I was just messing around with the width before I posted here. Before the width had been set at 200%, it still wasn't centering. I had defined width and length as twice the original length and width for the image, and it still wasn't centering.

Comment: Could you perhaps upload your image somewhere and add a link to it to your question? I can then try to reproduce your issue with the exact same image.

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the text-align to the container P and not the image.

```
.display
{
text-align: center;
}
```

You should also avoid scale operations on images (200%) as that consumes browser resources.  Just get a higher res version at the size you want, or resize the image in another application.  Most of the time the size of the file will only increase slightly in either scenario for png or jpg.

Comment: ive tried inputting that into the css as well, and it hasn't worked

Comment: Hit the F5 button to refresh the page and reload the CSS.

Comment: Did you read the question? OP clearly says their CSS is: `p.display {text-align:center;}`

Answer (score 0):

Looks pretty good to me.  Do you have any other style rules for this page?  Check that you aren't changing your `p` tags `display` attribute (it needs to be `block` to effectively align center.  Also make sure you aren't doing any `float`ing with the image.

You might also try removing `width="200%"` and using CSS to set the width.

If none of this works, post some additional code, or put the website public somewhere where we can take a closer look.

Comment: this is part of the `div.main` where the `float` is defined as `float:right;` if I was to change the float within `p.display` to `float:none;` would that work?

Comment: Floating is going to collapse everything to be the width of its content.  I question why your `div.main` would be floating right, but try setting a `width` property for your `p.display`, something larger than the image, and you should see the centering behavior.  For example: `<p class="display" style="width: 1000px;">...`

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be working right now (minus the `width="200%"` part), so it is probably a floating issue.

What do you wish to accomplish? If you wish to center the image across the entire page, take it out of your `float: right;` div. If you wish to center your image in just your small `float: right;` div (maybe as a sidebar on the right), do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/8vFHW/1/

Of course, you should replace your code with your icons and text, but the same concept is present.

Answer (score 0):

just add this and the project should be fixed! happy coding!

```
<CENTER>
    <a href="http://www.minecraft.net">
        <img src="Images/mclogo.png" width="200%" alt="Minecraft logo linked to MC's website" />
    </a></p>
</CENTER>
```